# Why is the value param nullable in Observer from Android Architecture Components?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

LiveData from architecture components defines an Observer with nullable value for the receiver callback:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(@Nullable T t);
}
```

**Why is there an explicitly nullable annotation?**

The doc of `LiveData.observe()` also says:

> If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.

E.g. Observer waits for non-nullable updates or immediately receive previous non-nullable value, that should hold especially in Kotlin, until I define `T` as nullable.

The code seem to be working like that. I understand why this doesn't hold for `LiveData.getValue()`, which may be called manually before first data is delivered (and checks therefore for `mData != NOT_SET` to return a null).

So the second question is: **Is is safe to assume the value is non-null in Kotlin when T is non-nullable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed in** `androix.lifecycle 2.0.0-beta01`.

Please report [android Team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80002881) if you encounter any issues.

Comment: I have reported the issue here after this SO discussion: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80002881. Though, not sure how it's currently fixed (hopefully the annotation is removed :D) - I can't find public source code for the new jetpack's library.

Comment: Actually, alpha02 was never released, beta01 contains the fix :)

Answer (score 2):

1. I think the fact that they made it Nullable is that they wanted to add the functionality for those who want to `reset` the liveData by nulling it's value. Also someone might want a nullable LiveData (and use that null in observe).
2. If you are creating/producing the LiveData, you could assume it is null (and use the `!!` operator) since a null would indicate an unexpected error.  Also you could create a class like NonNullLiveData that ignores the values that are null in it's `setValue`. That way you could be sure that you never recieve nulls in your observe (although you can't make the `@Nullable` go away from the observer).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `2.0.0-beta01` and later `androidx.lifecycle` version the `onChanged`parameter no longer contains `@Nullable` annotation. The changes is due to the [improvement request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80002881) courtesy by the OP.

```
package androidx.lifecycle;

/**
 * A simple callback that can receive from {@link LiveData}.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the parameter
 *
 * @see LiveData LiveData - for a usage description.
 */
public interface Observer<T> {
    /**
     * Called when the data is changed.
     * @param t  The new data
     */
    void onChanged(T t);
}
```

**Is is safe to assume the value is non-null in Kotlin when T is non-nullable?**

It depends, if you're the one who created the `LiveData` subclass or plainly using the existing `MutableLiveData` and you design it that it will never return null then it is safe to assume that it will never return null.

For the case that the `LiveData` is implicitly created by not you especially those `LiveData` that are provided by Libraries, I would not assume it is non-null unless the library documentation mentioned it.

Comment: > As you can see the mVersion is incremented by 1 which means that the Observer must need an update.

Yes, that makes sense but that's somehow obvious from the general rule that T is a subtype of Object and that may be a null in Java. But this code snippet make is obvious that there is an definitely non-symetric nullability annotation - `setValue()` misses `@Nullable`. Personally. I would do to opposite, remove the nullable in the observer.

Comment: @hrach I also use the Androidx version but it is still the same.

Comment: not sure what have you used and which version you've used in your edits on June 11, but the beta01 contains the Observer without Nullable annotation. My initial comments still hold and point to the symmetry too ;)

Comment: It was `2.0.0-alpha02` It's in my edit, I'll recheck it again after I have free time.

Comment: Weird, alpha02 doesn't seem to be tagged: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime

Comment: Sorry my mistake it is supposed to be `2.0.0-alpha1`. I accidentally copied the `android.arch` and not the `androidx.lifecycle` version of my work. Though that version has a Nullable annotation, I'll just compare it later with the beta version.

Comment: @hrach I updated my answer prior to your issue tracker request.