# Can the List in a LiveData returned from a Room DAO ever be null?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

This is a method in my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY priority DESC")
LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();
```

And I observe it in my MainActivity:

```
noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Note> notes) {
            adapter.setNotes(notes);
        }
```

`onChanged` is annotated with `@Nullable`, but will I ever actually get `null`? If yes, under which circumstances? If the table is empty, I get a `List` with size 0.

Comment: did you check `getAllNotes()` generated source code?

Comment: No, can you tell me how I can access the generated code?

Comment: in your DAO: `LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();` you have small blue (or green or turquoise??) circle on the left (i'm assuming you are using android studio) - click on it

Comment: Thanks. If I understand the code correctly, it always creates a `new ArrayList` from `cursor.getCount`. So from my logic it shouldn't be `null`. But I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: i have no sources in front of my eyes, but as i remember it works exactly like you said

Comment: It looks like always return ComputableLiveData which always set in his constructor  mLiveData = new LiveData<T>(); . So, yes it will not be NULL, if doesn't found anything will return empty list

Comment: What confuses me is that the `new ArrayList` is created in a `try` block. But there is no `catch` block, only `finally`.
But if the query doesn't fit to the `List` I want to return, Room wouldn't let me compile, right?

Comment: It's nullable because there are other uses of Livedata... not just Room

Comment: Thanks! According to this question, they removed the `@Nullable` annotation from the `observe` method in the newer versions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292394/why-is-the-value-param-nullable-in-observer-from-android-architecture-components